# Why won't my customized button's value cannot be saved in my database?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, mysql

I have a customized button for my data to make it active or inactive, the problem is it doesn't fetch the value in my query it always returns for example `undefined index: my_variable`. I am not sure if I am missing something cause what I have tried is I put `type=" button"` and `type=" checkbox"` in it but still it didn't work. I hope someone can help me through this. I've been stuck

Here is my CSS

```
    <style>
    .statusButton {
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 20px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 6px 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        border-radius: 5px;
        user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
```

Here is my customized button and its query to get value for rows

```
<?php 
include('../include/header_ps.php');

    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $query = "SELECT ID, status FROM tools_spec WHERE ID = '$ID'";
    $con->next_result();
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

?>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label"> Status <font color="red">*
  </font>
  </label>
    <div class="form-group">
     <p type="checkbox" name="update_stats" data-id="<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>"
      class="status_checks statusButton <?php echo ($rows['status'])? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>"
      >
       <?php echo ($rows['status'])? 'Active' : 'Inactive'?>
     </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in my PHP

```
<?php 

include('../include/connect.php');

    if(isset($_POST['updateSpec']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $update_model_num = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strtoupper($_POST['update_model_num']));
        $update_sect_value = strtoupper($_POST['update_value']);
        $update_sect_days = strtoupper($_POST['update_num_days']);
        $update_stats = $_POST['update_stats'];
        $update_reason = $_POST['reason_input_elem'];
    }

    $query = "UPDATE tools_spec 
    SET model_num = '$update_model_num', model_num_val = '$update_sect_value' , no_of_days = 
    '$update_sect_days',
    status = '$update_stats', reason_stats = '$update_reason'
    WHERE ID = '$id'";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $con->next_result();
    echo "<script> $('#update_ts_Modal').modal('show'); </script>";

?>
```

Comment: Hi , only input tags gets submitted to server . So,change `p` to `<input..` and try again.

Comment: Hi @Swati yeah I changed it but still not responding. I am so confused. Here is my code in my input.
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"
data-on="<?php if($rows['status'] == '1') { echo 'Active'; }?>"
data-off="<?php if($rows['status'] == '0'){ echo 'Inactive'; }?>"
name="update_stats" data-id="<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>"
class="status_checks statusButton <?php echo ($rows['status']) ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'?>">

Comment: Also , `$_GET['ID'];` ? your input name is `name="update_stats"` change that as well and put `value="<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>"` .

Comment: I am so sorry I got a little confused, uhmm what do you mean by $_GET['ID']; ?

Comment: where you are getting undefined ? there are two php codes you have posted :P may be i am getting confuse . Also , how data submit ?

Comment: Haha. Editted my code. Sorry, my fault, I split the php query for $rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228507/discussion-between-any-something-and-swati).

Comment: @Swati Hi sorry to disturb you again. I have additional question. When we set the checkbox into checked It worked for active status but when inactive status it has still check. It should disappear if the data is inactive because it's value is 0 how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to use that variable which doesn't contain any values. It ma be due to incorrect variable name. Check your table weather the given table column name exist or not. If exist then please check your query.

Echo out your id so that you can check the id has values in it. Hope this will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add form tag to submit (try) and if this doesn't work then create a button and set hidden and use little javascript and make it like
on click of div it should click button to

```
<button id="subbtn">Submit</button>
<div onclick="clickbtnto">
blah blah
</div>
<script>
function clickbtnto{
document.getelementbyid('subbtn').click;
}
</script>
```